# How fast can I send a UIImage between an iPhone and Apple Watch, with watchOS 2?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, apple-watch, watchos-2

I'm building an Apple WatchOS 2 app which is continuously animated with generated images.

Because these can't be bundled with the app, they're generated in InterfaceController, and then set to display on the watch like so:

```
self.imageGroup?.setBackgroundImage(self.image)
```

Until this point, I've been generating these at a rate of 1 image per second, which feels fairly safe, but obviously gives a very low framerate of 1fps. Now I'm wondering how much this could be improved?

I measured the speed at which the UIImages themselves are generated, which is a fairly low .017 seconds. The size of these images is fairly consistent, too at about 10000 bytes. If there was no further delay, that'd give me a much more acceptable performance of about 58fps.

My question is - Is there a typical speed at which bluetooth communicates with my phone, which I could compare to that image size to determine a realistic frame rate?

Or - I presume that calling `setBackgroundImage` doesn't block the main thread while that happens. Is there a way that I can find out how long it takes for that to actually be set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple doesn't have this speed documented because so much of it depends on connection strength. And since a user doesn't need to have the watch and phone right next to each other, the further away (or the type of objects between the phone and watch) a user is the slower it will transfer.

Your images are 10 KB, and you want to send 58 images per second so 580 KB or .58 MB per second? The amount of data doesn't sound unrealistic (though it will be a battery drain). However, each network call between the two devices will have some overhead. Do these image need to be sent in real time? If not you would likely get better performance if you could delay for 1-2 seconds initially and then batch a group of 58 images together which you would them animate on the watch. You would only have 1 network call every second which would be more more manageable for the devices than 58 calls per second.